# Convert anonymous type with nested dictionaries to human-readable string for testing purposes

Tags: c#

I have to test an ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper which is passed an object of an anonymous type with nested fields and dictionaries. For testing purposes I want to convert this thingy into a human-readable string.

Example:

```
var valueB = new Dictionary<string,object>();
valueB.Add("Key1", "ValueB1");
valueB.Add("Key2", "ValueB2");
var obj = new { PropA = "ValueA", PropB = valueB };
```

I want to convert obj into a human-readable string, e.g., into something like this:

```
( (PropA=ValueA), (PropB=( (Key1,ValueB1), (Key2,ValueB2) )) )
```

How to do that in a very *simple* and *easy* way such that the test code can be easily read and I don't have test infrastructure bloat.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: I'd suggest a simple Json serialization. Json.Net with the Indented option works great. The output is `{"Key1":"ValueB1","Key2":"ValueB2"}` for the dictionary and `{"PropA":"ValueA","PropB":{"Key1":"ValueB1","Key2":"ValueB2"}}` on the anon type.

Comment: @asawyer: Very good idea, thanks! My "home-brewn" solution isn't very neat in comparison. I think I'll give the JSON serialization a shot!